# How to remove some effects (hoverFlow)?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I'm working with [hoverFlow](http://www.2meter3.de/code/hoverFlow/demos.html) a JQuery plugin, so far work as I expected, however I would like to remove it when the screen is resized less than 799px and added it back when the screen is resized more than 800px. this is my code:

```
function setEffects() {
    if(document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 800){
        if($("#menu-main-nav-menu a span").length == 0){
            $("#menu-main-nav-menu a").append("<span>&nbsp</span>");
            $("#menu-main-nav-menu a").hover(function(e) {
            $(this).hoverFlow(e.type, { width: 248 }, 200)
                .css('overflow', 'visible')
                .find('span')
                .hoverFlow(e.type, { width: 5 }, 200)

            }, function(e) {
                $(this).hoverFlow(e.type, { width: 233 }, 200)
                    .css('overflow', 'visible')
                    .find('span')
                    .hoverFlow(e.type, { width: 20 }, 200)
            });
        }
    }else{
        if($("#menu-main-nav-menu a span").length != 0){
            $("#menu-main-nav-menu a").remove('span');
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(setEffects);
window.onresize = setEffects;
```

thanks in advance, if you have a question please let me know :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try unbinding the event:

```
$(this).unbind(e.type);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! but didn't work. I tried this
    $("#menu-main-nav-menu a").hover(function(e) {
           $(this).unbind(e.type);
    });
after the "else" statement

Comment: It looks like you would just change `$("#menu-main-nav-menu a").remove('span');` to `$(#menu-main-nav-menu a").unbind(e.type);`. Does your original code work? What is your html?

Comment: I have somthing like this: http://jsfiddle.net/z6y8k/3/ I haven't been able to make the effect works on jsfidle